# Qt Cannot open include file: 'QPrinter'

Tags: qt, include, qmake

I am new to Qt. Downloaded source code for a Qt application of SourceForge, and tried to build and run it. After working through a few similar problems by adding `QT +=` statements to .pro files, I am stuck on this one:

On attempting to build in Qt Creator, I get errors saying

> error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QPrinter': No such file or directory

I tried adding `QT += printsupport` to the .pro file, cleaning, and rebuilding, but that gives this error

> Error: dependent '..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\include\QtPrintSupport\qtprintsupportglobal.h' does not exist."

When I go to `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\include\QtPrintSupport`, qtprintsupportglobal.h IS THERE!

Comment: There is no project-specific path that I need to edit, is there?

Comment: Delete the shadow build directory and build again, just in case.

Answer (score 22):

You have to add QPrinter Support to your project's .pro file:

```
QT += printsupport
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the solution was to

> Delete the shadow build directory and build again

**after** adding `printsupport`, as @KubaOber suggests in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Because QMake will eventually be dropped in favor of CMake, here's the solution for CMake users:

Pass `PrintSupport` to the `find_package` call, to the right side of `COMPONENTS`, like in this example:

```
find_package(Qt5 ${QT5_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Qml QuickControls2 PrintSupport)
```

Comment: For Qt6 and CMake see here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtprintsupport-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Easy mistake to make: After you edit your .pro

```
QT       += printsupport
```

You have to SAVE the file before your .h will be aware of it.